# Unsupported option provided to mysql_options()

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed mysql-server and mysql-workbench on my local machine having Ubuntu 16.04 as OS. I am able to connect to mysql-server through CLI, but not through mysql-workbench.

```
  mysql --version
  mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.12, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

mysql-workbench --version
MySQL Workbench CE (GPL) 6.3.6 CE build 511
```

I am consistently getting this error from mysql-workbench when i try to connect to mysql-server.

```
Unsupported option provided to mysql_options()
```

please help me to understand what i am doing wrong to fix this issue i.e. to get connected to mysql-server through mysql-workbench.

Comment: Does anything useful appear in the [logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-reporting-bugs.html)?

Comment: Which logs can you help me? so that I can post that too.

Comment: What is [`old_passwords`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_old_passwords) set to?  Since [v6.3.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-6-3-6.html), Workbench no longer supports the [Pre-4.1 (“old”) hashing protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/old-client.html) that's provided by the  `mysql_old_password` plugin—i.e. indicated by `old_passwords=1`.

Comment: @eggyal I have set mysql password to 'root'.

Comment: I was asking what the [system variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html) that is named `old_passwords` is set to.

Comment: @eggyal can you tell me how to get its value?

Comment: Have you followed *any* of the links I provided so far?  The "system variable" one, in particular, explains how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

The server variable **mysql_old_password** protocol is no longer supported by Workbench, as its support was removed in MySQL Server 5.7. This affects the former "**Use old authentication protocol**" SSH connection option in the MySQL Workbench which causes the error

> Unsupported option provided to mysql_options()

while you have attempted to establish the connection via workbench. So upgrade MySQL-Workbench to any newer version to avoid this error.

Please check this URL for reference :
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78947

Comment: I dont know why this post has been down voted. 
@SachinSingh, Please provide me the mysql-error log and I ll get you the solution to fix the problem if the above said method is not working.

Comment: i have not down voted it, please let me which logs you want and also tell me the process to get them thanks for your reply.

Comment: Fine. I hope you have installed the mysql using apt-get. If so, the the error log will be under "/var/logs/mysql/"

Comment: Before that, check the my.cnf whether the error log has been enabled or not. Else it might be configured in some other path.

Answer (score 2):

To fix that issue.
What you can do is  to downgrade the MySQL Workbench CE (GPL) 6.3.6 to version [6.3.4](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/file/mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-1ubu1504-amd64.deb)

Comment: I am now trying to downgrade from 6.3.10 to 6.3.4-r1 on Gentoo system.   As per bug simply newest workbench doesn't support this option as removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the details - it is shame I cannot connect to older systems (actually it is database running on Centos 7...)

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78947

Update: 
On my Gentoo system I got it working locally with versions:

- mysql-workbench - 6.3.10
- mariadb - 10.1.31-r1 (I found note about
  latest mariadb version doesn't work as well here:
  https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1073876-start-0.html)

But it didn't work straightforward, I had to delete folder ~/.mysql/workbench first, otherwise this error still occured, now I have setup where this issue is fixed.

Comment: is it a question or an answer?