# Another Unsupported operation provided to mysql_options()

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect to a local mysql server (5.6.37) running on linux (gentoo) using mysql workbench (6.3.9). I get an "Unsupported operation provided to mysql_options()" error message and cannot connect. I am aware of [the very similar question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026699/unsupported-option-provided-to-mysql-options/37468831), [the bug report about the issue](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78947) and [the supposed fix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-upgrades.html).

However, none of the suggested solutions seem to apply in my case. The system variable `old_passwords` is not enabled (ie is set to 0) and all users are using the `mysql_native_password` plugin explicitly, as described in the fix. I am at a loss on what to try next. Can someone help me figure out what I've missed?

Thanks

Comment: I'd try connecting from a bash shell first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have mentioned I have no problem connecting from the regular mysql shell.

Comment: Connecting via a socket might be an option.

Comment: Same error via a socket.

Comment: Maybe try Workbench (6.3.4) or Mysql 5.7.

Comment: I know this is not mysql or mysql workbench's problem, but workbench 6.3.4 no longer seems to compile correctly on gentoo and mysql 5.7 is not in their (non masked) repositories yet.